# Filter in datatable with php forgets the filter when I go to next page of datatable

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that I have a filter working for my datatables, but when I go to next page it forgets the filter and shows all the data in the table, any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your efforts (code) so far?

Comment: php persistence can be done using sessions. you can store the filter criteria in a session variable and call the sql with it on the next page. depending on the type of datatable, this is should be a JS issue.

Comment: probably if your pulling data from ajax then you need to add filter in the service as well,

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is called a `pagination`.